# Angular posts an undefined file to nestjs controller

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, nestjs

I'm trying to upload a file from an Angular app to a nestjs backend but the controller gets an undefined file.
This is the Angular file service:

```
    async create(file: File): Promise<string> { 
        // With console.log I can see file is defined
        // file comes directly from the input file (event.target.files[0])
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers
            .set(
               'Content-Type',
               `multipart/form-data; boundary=-----${guid.v4()}`
            )
            .set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return await this.http.post<string>('/api/files', formData, { headers }).toPromise();
    }
```

And this the controller method:

```
    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async create(@UploadedFile() file: any) {
        return await this.files.create(file.buffer);
    }
```

The http interceptor says: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined`.
I tried to upload files with postman and it works, I guess I am missing something in my angular code.

Comment: What was your workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution for this issue yet. I needed for a personal project that I had to put on hold for the moment. Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Try remove the `multipart/form-data` header? It seems excessive to me. I've done simple post requests from angular almost identically to that without that header set manually like you do and it works with multer / FileInterceptor.

Comment: Yes, removing the header worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this is your create() function:

```
return this.http.patch<any>(
      `${this.domain}/users/avatar/upload/${id}`,
      formData,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set("Accept", "application/json")    // <=== there is the point      
      }
    );
```

this worked for me.